# Applying a queuing service policy

Tags: cisco, qos, cisco-nexus

This is on a Nexus N5624Q.

I have this TA-queuing service policy :

```
policy-map type queuing TA-queuing
  class type queuing queue-cos1
    bandwidth percent 20
  class type queuing queue-cos2
    bandwidth percent 10
  class type queuing queue-cos4
    bandwidth percent 15
  class type queuing queue-cos5
    bandwidth percent 5
  class type queuing class-fcoe
    bandwidth percent 0
class-map type queuing queue-cos1
  match qos-group 2
class-map type queuing queue-cos2
  match qos-group 3
class-map type queuing queue-cos4
  match qos-group 4
class-map type queuing queue-cos5
  match qos-group 5
```

When I want to apply the service policy on an interface, I get an error stating "Bandwidth percent exceeds 100" :

```
N5624-A-1(config-if)# service-policy type queuing input TA-queuing
ERROR: Bandwidth percent exceeds 100
```

But the bandwidth parameters do not add up to 100, they only add up to 50, so I don't understand why this error keeps happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default-class uses (by default) 50 percent of the available bandwidth.  You can reduce that value as part of your policy-map.  For example:

```
policy-map type queuing TA-queuing
...
class-type queuing class-default
  bandwidth 25
```

Comment: Also, by default, you can only assign something like 75% of the bandwidth. That's why it will add up to 125%.

Answer (score 0):

Note: On any interface only 75% of the bandwidth is available for QoS.

Comment: While your answer is, by default, correct, you should improve your answer by quoting this from the Cisco documentation, and providing a link to support your answer. You can find the `max-reserved-bandwidth` command in Cisco's QoS documentation.